# Dockerized MongoDB Failing to connect on Heroku from NodeJs Container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, heroku

i have a node web service and I'm a bit new to docker, so please bear with me.  Below is my docker-compose file.  I have run this image locally and it works fine, but when trying to deploy it to Heroku I get the following error:

```
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo mongo:27017]
```

I've found where I'm supposed to set the environment flags in Heroku, so I managed to check that and its fine.  But it still can't find mongo:27017

What could I be doing wrong?

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/charecters
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-seed:
    build: ./mongo-seed
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-seed:/mongo-seed
    command:
      - /mongo-seed/script.sh
  app:
    container_name: app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
    environment:
      - DB_SERVERS=mongo:27017
```

Answer (score -3):

```
links:
      - mongo

is depreciated try 

depends_on:
     - mongo

also, check that 

mongo:
    container_name: mongo, is properly referenced in DB setup

change command:
  - /mongo-seed/script.sh

try command:
   - 'node your-app-file'
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. For future readers it's far more interesting to see explained *why* this answers the question.